# How does the Operating System call routines from an application?

Tags: process, callback, io, system

When an application performs some IO operation, the application in question needs to be informed when the IO operation is finished, and who performs this role is the operating system. However, I would like to know how the OS manages to inform the application that a certain event has been completed? If it is through the registration of callbacks, how can the OS call the application context through these callbacks when the OS and the Application are different processes in memory?